# creating new instance of unknown class using property file

Tags: java, instantiation, properties-file

so i got a homework from my teacher to implement a class using his interface.
the name of the interface is "Position". i managed to write the code and it seems to work fine.

we are free to name our implementation-class as we want but need to define the class-name in a properties-file("ewn.properties") with the key "position-implementation" and the fully qualified classname as value
`position-implementation = programmieren.aufgabe4.PositionImplementation`. 
at the end we have to export the project as a jar (my class + the properties-file).

so far so good.

now i wanted to test my solution. i created a new project, package and a main class and imported both jars (mine and the one from my teacher).

here is the code of the test-class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Properties prop = new Properties();
    InputStream in = Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/programmieren/aufgabe4/ewn.properties");
    try {
        prop.load(in);

        Class<?> clazz = (Class<?>) Class.forName(prop
                .getProperty("position-implementation"));

        System.out.println(clazz.toString());

        Position p = (Position) clazz.newInstance();

        p.toString();

    } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException
            | ClassNotFoundException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

my problem is that i don't know how to create a new instance of my implementation class.
i tried to use the interface as declaration type but my object returns nothing after calling:

```
    p.toString();
```

but it should print something like this:

```
    ------------
    ------------
    ------------
    ------------
    ------------
    ------------
```

also this line:

```
    System.out.println(clazz.toString());
```

gives me the following output:
`class programmieren.aufgabe4.Position` but it should be `class programmieren.aufgabe4.PositionImplementation` shouldn't it?

Comment: You not printing the p.toString() that will return a String variable so do System.out.println(p.toString());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question 1 : You are just doing the method call and not printing

`System.out.println(p.toString());`

This will print it

Question 2 : Override `String toString()` method in the below Implementation class as well

`programmieren.aufgabe4.PositionImplementation`

```
@override
public String toString(){
return this.class.getName();
}
```

Otherwise, it would invoke the `toString()` method belonging to any closer level super class. If it doesn't find any override of `toString()` method in the inheritance tree, then the `Object.toString()` method will be executed. Since all instances are of type `Object`

Comment: i did override the `toString()` method in `programmieren.aufgabe4.PositionImplementation` :(

edit: oh man! what a dumb mistake... thank you very much!
but shouldn't `System.out.println(clazz.toString)` return the classname of my implementation?

Comment: Are you sure that the object created is of type `PositionImplementation`? Can you double check it?

Comment: yeah now it prints the desired outcome :).

Comment: Glad it helped..Can you please accept and close the question :)